# Segmentation Fault when using 3D array to linear index macro for three dimensional poisson multiplication

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, macros, segmentation-fault

I was hoping someone could help with the below, I can't figure out whats going wrong. The below function is used to multiply a 3 Dimensional Matrix and a vector using the 3D Laplacian, although thats not necessary to know for the issue. I've created two macros at the beginning of the function to map from a 3D geometric space to a linear memory space.

The segmentation fault appears when using the macro to access the element X(0,0,0) from X(i,j-1,k), ie for the case when current loop is i=0,j=1,k=0, (0,1,0), for a system with n_x, n_y and n_z =100 (100x100x100). Therefore the macro will change the 3D geometry (0,0,0) to the linear index 0, this can be confirmed by printing. Accessing x[0] is fine when printing. and printing the results of the macro also gives zero.

Sorry for the vagueness, hoping it's maybe something simple I'm doing wrong with the macros? I'm allocating the arrays using dynamic memory.

```
void matvec_mul(int N,int n_x, int n_y, int n_z,double* restrict Ax,double* restrict x){
 #define X(i,j,k) (x[(i*n_y*n_z)+(j*n_z)+k])
 #define AX(i,j,k) (Ax[(i*n_y*n_z)+(j*n_z)+k])
 int inv_h2 = (n_x-1)*(n_x-1);
 for (int i = 0; i < n_x; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n_y; ++j) {
   for (int k = 0; k < n_z; ++k) {
    printf("%i,%i,%i\n",i,j,k);
    printf("%i\n",(i*n_y*n_z)+(j*n_z)+k);
    double xx = X(i,j,k);
    double xn = (i > 0) ? X(i-1,j,k) : 0;
    double xs = (i < n_x-1) ? X(i+1,j,k) : 0;
    printf("Seg faults on next line\n");
    double xe = (j > 0) ? X(i,j-1,k) : 0;
    double xw = (j < n_y-1) ? X(i,j+1,k) : 0;
    double xu = (k > 0) ? X(i,j,k-1) : 0;
    double xd = (k < n_z-1) ? X(i,j,k+1) : 0;
    AX(i,j,k) = (6*xx - xn - xs - xe - xw - xu - xd)/inv_h2;
   }
  }
 }
#undef AX
#undef X
}
```

Comment: For the love of obfuscation, please use a 3D array! `array[i][j][k]` not `#define X(i,j,k) (x[(i*n_y*n_z)+(j*n_z)+k])`.

Comment: You need parentheses around the macro parameters in the macro replacement text.

Comment: I'm porting the code to CUDA to implement on a GPU later in the project so using a linear memory space from the beginning to make things a bit easier later. That worked Ian, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does CUDA support variable length arrays in function parameters (which are automagically converted to pointers of course)? It's a standard C construct since C99.

Comment: I.e. does CUDA support `void matvec_mul(int N,int n_x, int n_y, int n_z,double restrict Ax[n_x][n_y][n_z],double restrict x[n_x][n_y][n_z])`? It would save all the farting about with macros.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due lack of parentheses around the macro parameters in the macro replacement text.

Change the macro definitions to the following:

```
#define X(i,j,k) (x[((i)*n_y*n_z)+((j)*n_z)+(k)])
#define AX(i,j,k) (Ax[((i)*n_y*n_z)+((j)*n_z)+(k)])
```

With your original macros, `X(i,j-1,k)` would be expanded to `(x[(i*n_y*n_z)+(j-1*n_z)+k])` but you want `(x[(i*n_y*n_z)+((j-1)*n_z)+k])`. (Note the difference between `(j-1*n_z)` and `((j-1)*n_z)`.) With the new macros, the replacement is `(x[((i)*n_y*n_z)+((j-1)*n_z)+(k)])`.